# Differentiate Value of Unmarked Potentiometers

Tags: potentiometer

I am constructing a signal generator using a kit. Upon soldering it together, I have encountered a problem. The board is marked with two potentiometer slots, identical except for the values named on the board: 50K for the amplitude control and 1K for the offset control. I have two potentiometers, nearly identical. One of them is completely unmarked. The other has B503 etched on the back. How can I tell which one is 50K and which is 1K?

Thanks.

Comment: Measure them using a Ohm meter.

Comment: Seconding the previous comment, I would also guess that B503 is 50K (50*10^3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B503 is probably a 50K pot with a 'B' (linear) taper.

But to measure it, just measure the element with a multimeter.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

B503 should be \$50\text k\Omega\$, and the other \$1\text k\Omega\$. As stated in comments, measure to confirm.